# One to many relationship in laravel5

Tags: laravel, model, relationship, one-to-many

I have to tables Branch and Association,
and Branch table has one to many relationship with Association.
I have done the relationship in both model.
Now I want to get the number of associations related to each branch.
Could anyone please solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have models and built the relations.

```
$branches=Branch::with('associations')->get();
foreach($branches as $branch)
{
      foreach($branch->associations as $association)
      {
            print_r($associtaion->name);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The simple way

You can simply use

```
$branch->associations()->count();
```

### A more efficient way

A more efficient way is as follows which you can find in [this github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2813):

Branch Model:

```
public function associationCountRelation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Association::class)->select(DB::raw('id, count(*) as count'))->groupBy('id');
}

public function getAssociationCountAttribute()
{
    return $this->associationCountRelation->count;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$branch = Branch::with('associationCountRelation')->find($id);

echo $branch->associationCount;
```